# gource display LIVE svn

Tags: bash, svn, gource

Im trying to have a gource window display "LIVE" events from an SVN repo..

What i have is :

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

bash test2.sh | gource --realtime --path - --log-format svn --colour-images \
    --highlight-users --file-extensions --follow-user sam --user-scale 2 \
    --file-idle-time 0 \
    --logo /var/www/proppolis/src/Nono/AdminBundle/Resources/public/images/logo-proppolis-01.png \
    --hide filenames,dirnames --camera-mode track
```

test2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( ; ; ))
do
    svn log http://101.101.101.101:9880/proppolis -r HEAD --username XXX --password XXX --verbose --xml --quiet
    sleep 10
done
```

THis works as in: every 10 seconds, it gets the log from HEAD revision, and STDOUT's it to gource

But as soon as i remove  "-r HEAD"   or make it into anything else,   like   0:HEAD  or  150   or whatever,   it goes haywire and tells me that gource cant read the log format ??

ps: running the svn command DOES in fact generate a valid log ...

thx in advaace

Comment: ps: imporved this a little, to actually show all new commits only once,   this is a really cool thing to have hanging in a common area of your company, and look at development live .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/whitewhidow/live-git-for-gource for a complete solution for live git and live svn visualisation in gource (created long after this question was asked)